# CSS functions won’t update on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, dns

For some reason CSS won’t update on my domain after uploading to FTP , but updates on other browsers like Microsoft Edge.

It used to update all the time 100% on chrome but for some reason has stopped.
Looking for intel on why this may have happened?
If anyone else has experienced this problem?
And how I can potentially fix this?

THE HTML HEAD

```
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-real.png" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+SC:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Thasadith:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Imanto Contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, this happens because chrome caches stylesheets. You can try changing the link rel in your html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css?v=2">
```

(style.css is your stylesheet filename)
This will make all browsers load your stylesheet from server. YOU DO NOT HAVE TO CHANGE THE STYLESHEET FILENAME, JUST CHANGE ABOVE LINE.

Let me know if this doesn't work, I will check again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: <head> of html and stylesheet name

Comment: So the problem is with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">`, you have tried `href="main.css?v=2"` and it didn't work?

Comment: Hmm, I must have done it wrong the first time. Oh well, you solved it! cheers bruz you're a legend.

Answer (score 0):

You also can press the shortcut for a hard reload ctrl+shift+r.
In this case, every extern style/code sheets are reloaded.
Another way is to open the dev tools using f12 and then press the reload button long and click on hard reload or cache reload.
Sorry for my bad English.